# Can't download Docs package in Fedora Container Image

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

I don't know what I am doing wrong but the Fedora Container image is not installing doc packages.

`yum install ansible-core-doc`

Claims to successfully install, but `/usr/share/doc/ansible-core-doc/` doesn't exist.
To make doubly certain I am looking in the correct place I checked
`dnf repoquery -l ansible-core-doc`
And non of these files exist.

I suspect it is the `yum --nodocs` flag being set somewhere but I can't find it being set in the environment or the config files.

> I understand it is a good thing this is set by default in the container image, I am not building a image, I just wanted access to the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`

```
# see `man dnf.conf` for defaults and possible options

[main]
gpgcheck=True
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
best=False
skip_if_unavailable=True
tsflags=nodocs
```

Just removing `tsflags=nodocs` works!